# Can "Remote Desktop Connection" use multiple connections (dual wan)

Tags: remote-desktop

Is "Remote Desktop Connection" capable of utilizing a dual wan setup and make multiple connections to the host, so that a single client will see improved speed?

If no, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That has nothing to do with RDP itself - but with your routing and load balancing on the wan-router/firewall - most likely: not possible unless you have some special setup.

tsg

Answer (score 0):

Not a particularly well worded question, but as Truebsalgeblaese has said it has nothing to do with RDP, more your routing setup. RDP is a single-session protocol, it can't be split across WANs at the application level, your best bet is to bond your WANs or just get a better line.

On the other hand, if you list off the problems you're seeing and explain your current WAN setup we might be able to give you some help in suggesting improvements elsewhere to achieve this.